# Unity c# - How can I make it so that I can access all my other classes, variables and methods via a single class?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

So i have a bunch of classes written in a way so that they can be re-used across different projects.

To tidy things up a little, make it easier to access and to avoid conflicts I've been trying to put them all into one class.

For example, if i have these three classes

```
public class Head
{
   public string eye_color = "blue";
   public string hair_color = "black";

   public void nod()
   {
      //some code to nod
   }
}

public class Body
{
   public string type = "athletic";
}

public class Hands
{
   public int fingers = 10;
}
```

I would like to stick them all into a Person class so that everything in those classes can be called/accessed with something like

```
private Person person = new Person(); 
Debug.Log(person.body.type);
person.head.nod();
```

So currently the approach i am taking is to setup the person class something like this

```
public class Person
{
   public Head head = new Head();
   public Body body = new Body();
   public Hands hands = new Hands();
}
```

The format being MainClassInstance.SomeOtherClassReferencedInTheMainClassInstance.SomeMethodOrVariable - i need it all to be accessed via that first MainClass.

For the most part this seems to work. However, I'm coming across a few issues with classes that are Monobehaviour and also with static variables. These can't be accessed with an instance.

How can i deal with these so that I can continue to call/access everything in the same way (as described above)?

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment :-)

Comment: well so far so good ... if some values are [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) there is no way to "limit" the acces to them .. because they don't "belong" to one instance of a class but instead to the class itself and you acces them via the class not the instance like e.g. `Body.BodyCounter`

Comment: I don't fully understand if you are talking about nested classes using what you mentioned `MainClass.SomeOtherClassinsideTheMainClass.SomeMethodOrVariable` or (what I believe and what your code samples look like) you are actually talking about references in field within those classes and actually mean `MainClassInstance.SomeOtherClassReferencedInTheMainClassInstance.SomeMethodOrVariable`

Comment: @derHugo this is what im currently having to do but ... i don't like it lol. Its just so much nicer if i can call/access everything through that main class

Comment: @derHugo yes you got it sorry i might edit what i wrote. I'm looking to access it all via the instance created with the Person person = new Person(); instance

Comment: As said before there is no chance to limit that access for `static` members ... except making them not `static` anymore but usually there is a reason why they are `static` ^^

Comment: @derHugo you're right. there are only a few unavoidable ones. thanks anyway :-)

Comment: You can access static properties through instances if you use reflection, or you can create instance methods that get/set the static properties.

Answer (score -1):

If this is purely to fix issues relating to conflicts and re-used variable names etc. I think what you actually want is a namespace, rather than using an empty class that's simply holding a bunch of other classes for no real reason. I could be wrong though, do you always want your group of classes to be instantiated together? Do you require a Head Body and Hands instantiated together every single time because of some interdependency? Or are they all actually separate and have no direct dependency to eachother? In the latter case, it would likely be better to store them in a namespace together, rather than a class.

As for your primary question, accessing static variables on an instance is performed by doing:

```
public class Head
{
    public static int eyeCount;
    public int eyelashCount;

    public GrowEyeLash()
    {
        eyelashCount++; //accessing a normal variable
    }

    public SetEyeCount(int eyes)
    {
        Head.eyeCount = eyes; //accessing a static variable
    }
}
```

When you want to access a static variable, you use the class rather than an instance, since a static variable is associated with the type itself, not any particular instance. Essentially, a static variable only exists in one place in your code, and applies to *all* instances.